# how to use react-motion library with modals

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, react-motion

I am using react-modal to create modals, and trying to slide the modal from bottom of page. For that i am trying react-motion TransitionMotion Component. My code is:

```
{ this.state.openNumberPopup &&
  <TransitionMotion
    styles={[{key: 'key',style: this.getStyles()}] } 
  > 
   {
     (interpolated) => 
       <div> {
         interpolated.map(({ key, style, data }) => 
           <NumberPopup
             key={${key}-transition}
             style={{opacity: style.opacity,transform: scale(${style.scale})}}
             openNumberPopup={this.state.openNumberPopup}
             toggleNumberPopup={this.toggleNumberPopup}
             handleChange={this.handleChange}
             updateNumber={this.updateNumber}
             disableSubmit={this.state.disableSubmit} 
           />
         )
        } 
      </div>
    } 
  </TransitionMotion>
}
```

where getStyles is:

```
getStyles = () => ({ opacity: spring(1), scale: spring(1) });
```

but this is not working because modal component.

Comment: I was using TransitionMotion in wrong way. Instead i used Motion here.